# api google adwords how to get the report for ads?

Tags: ads, google-ads-api

i'm using the api google adwords for generating report , i can get it for the campaign , but i'm unable to generate report for ads ( i need to get the AdId , the AdName , clicks , impressions cost and many others data ).
what type of report should i use ? 
i tried with :

```
AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
```

and also with

```
AD_CUSTOMIZERS_FEED_ITEM_REPORT
```

but it returns error as "unknown fields" or it doesn't return anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution , here it is :

```
 $dateRange = sprintf('%d,%d',
      date('Ymd', strtotime('-7 day')), date('Ymd', strtotime('-1 day')));
    $reportQuery = 'SELECT Id,Headline, Impressions, Clicks, Cost, AdGroupId '
                    . ' FROM AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT '
                    . ' DURING '.$dateRange;

        // Download report.
        ReportUtils::DownloadReportWithAwql($reportQuery, $filePath, $user,$reportFormat, $options);
```

The report is : AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT and the variable for the name is Headline.
Hope it helps.